# CSS how set opacity deep

Tags: css

I'd like to set opacity of the user's avatar through all layers to 1 layer.
Is there a solution to this? Maybe something with z-index or something else?

[image]

Comment: That is not how opacity works - you can not set it “to a layer”. If you want the avatar images to “blend” with a specific background, then you have to set that background on the (/an) element that is behind them.

Comment: I see guys.. But may be is there anything else solution?
I like solution CBroe. Thank you. If i will not find another solution then I will use yours.

Comment: Unfortunately, as @CBroe said, the layers stack on top of each other, and there's no way to modify the parent containers with information on the children. You will have to "fake" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had to make the following assumption as you have not included any html / css with your question: Layer 1 is using a background image, as opposed to a fixed `<img.../>` tag with `z-index` set to below all other content.

This is the minimum amount of html/css I needed to make your example picture.

The trick here is `background-attachment: fixed`. This is like using `position:fixed` on any other element. This will place the background image (by default) at 0px x 0px relative to the window, not the document. By assigning this to layer 1 and layer 3 you can overlay the same background image over the elements to give the impression that layer3 is semi-transparent and viewing layer1.

Be aware that you are placing one image over another, so if you resize the background image on layer1 it will not look right on layer3. As such, you may want to have a very large background image that looks fine on any resolution.

To illustrate the "transparency" I have given layer2 a solid white background.

Keep clicking 'Run Code Snippet' to load a new set of images.

```css
.layer1,
.layer3 {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/800/sports/) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}
.layer2 {
  background-color:#fff;
  width:70%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.layer3 {
  display:inline-block;
}
.layer3 img {
  opacity:0.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="layer1">
  <div class="layer2">
    <ul>
      <li><div class="layer3"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/abstract/"/></div></li>
      <li><div class="layer3"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/city/"/></div></li>
      <li><div class="layer3"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/people/"/></div></li>
      <li><div class="layer3"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/transport/"/></div></li>
      <li><div class="layer3"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/cats/"/></div></li>
      <li><div class="layer3"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/sports/"/></div></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Keep layer "2" as a border css rule.

Break the layer "3" into separate components.

For the **Green** component: set the border size as per requirement and background **transparent**

For the **Red** component: set the background as **white** and other css rules as you please.

[image]